# What is the output of the native Float.floatToRawIntBits(float value)?

Tags: java, floating-point, int, native

The JRE documentation states that the native function `Float.floatToRawIntBits(Float value)`...

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value
>   according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout,
>   preserving Not-a-Number (NaN) values.

What is `"single format"` bit layout? I've never heard this expression.

I ran an example:

```
float f = 1;
System.out.println(Float.floatToRawIntBits(f));
```

Which outputs `1065353216`.

What is this function actually doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> IEEE 754 floating-point ``single format'' bit layout:
>
> Bit 31 of the result represents the sign of the float; bits 30 to 23
>   represent the (biased) exponent; bits 22 to 0 represent the mantissa.

The int returned is the integer representation of that 32bit string.

Wikipedia details how to convert a float into IEEE 754.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format